# SQL select current transaction and reference most recent transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, analytics

could use some SQL help in Oracle 11G.  I'm trying to create a result set that takes a current transaction, finds the most recent related transaction, shows the current price along with the previous price, and then calculates the difference.

Assume each item can only have one price for a given month.  If there's no earlier data available, then display the current value.

Raw data would look something like:

```
+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------+
| Item  | Location | Department |  MonthEnd  | Price |
+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------+
| Truck | Illinois | BusinessA  | 4/30/2014  | 10000 |
| Truck | Illinois | BusinessA  | 6/30/2014  |  9500 |
| Truck | Illinois | BusinessA  | 10/31/2014 |  8000 |
+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------+
```

And the query result would look something like:

```
+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------+------------------+---------------+------------+
| Item  | Location | Department |  MonthEnd  | Price | PreviousMonthEnd | PreviousPrice | PriceDelta |
+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------+------------------+---------------+------------+
| Truck | Illinois | BusinessA  | 10/31/2014 |  8000 | 6/30/2014        |          9500 |      -1500 |
| Truck | Illinois | BusinessA  | 6/30/2014  |  9500 | 4/30/2014        |         10000 |       -500 |
| Truck | Illinois | BusinessA  | 4/30/2014  | 10000 | 4/30/2014        |         10000 |          0 |
+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------+------------------+---------------+------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [Lag analytical function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php) to get that. The query will look like below.

```
SELECT Item,
       Location,
       Department,
       MonthEnd,
       Price,
       COALESCE(LAG (MonthEnd, 1) OVER (ORDER BY MonthEnd),  MonthEnd) PrevMonthEnd,
       COALESCE(LAG (Price, 1)    OVER (ORDER BY MonthEnd),  price)    PrevPrice ,
       (price - coalesce(LAG (Price, 1) OVER (ORDER BY MonthEnd), price)) PriceDelta
FROM   items
ORDER BY monthend desc
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle testing this.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b8cb/13)

Answer (score 1):

Use Analytic Function to generate `row_number` and `Left join` the result .Try this.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY MonthEnd DESC) rn

         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT a.Item,
       a.Location,
       a.Department,
       a.MonthEnd,
       a.Price,
       COALESCE(( a.Price - b.Price ), a.price)
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.rn = b.rn - 1
```

Note : Based on your requirement you may to add `Partition by` in `Over` clause

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution using Oracle's Analytical functions (using the Windowing clause though). You can find the modified version of @Sathya's [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b8cb/30)

Query is as below:

```
SELECT Item,
       Location,
       Department,
       MonthEnd,
       Price,
       MIN(monthend) OVER (PARTITION BY item,location,department ORDER BY item,location,department,monthend ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) PrevMonthEnd,
       NVL(SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item,location,department ORDER BY item,location,department,monthend ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),price) PrevPrice ,
       (price - NVL(SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item,location,department ORDER BY item,location,department,monthend ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),price)) PriceDelta
FROM   items
ORDER BY monthend DESC
```

Comment: Interesting approach... Rather winding one though!

Comment: @Sathya, thanks mate. And yeah, this isn't a straight forward approach compared to LAG for this particular case. But the actual problem OP is trying to address might be totally different (whereas the sample provided is just a striped down version of it). So thought, positing this would benefit OP or someone someday :-)